# “linux” grub loader can't detect android

Tags: shell, grub, boot-loader, android

I had installed Bliss OS.
[image]

I wasn't getting that in grub loader. That's why I was searching in Google little bit. I got [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/how-to-dual-boot-android-x86-and-ubuntu.html).

And, I added following code at the bottom of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /android-4.0-RC1/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=eeepc acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-4.0-RC1 SDCARD=/data/sdcard.img
initrd /android-4.0-RC1/initrd.img}
```

And, tried following command

```
root@istiak ~ # sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom  #permission 
root@istiak ~ # sudo update-grub           #updating grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

`/dev/sda2       209616896 272531455  62914560    30G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

I think I am having problem with `root='(hd0,2)'`. I didn't find `SDCARD=/data/sdcard.img`. There's only three `img` formatted file.Here are they.

```
/dev/sda1  *      1026048 209615761 208589714  99.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       209616896 272531455  62914560    30G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       272533504 273694719   1161216   567M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       274749438 625141759 350392322 167.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       274749440 623142911 348393472 166.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       623144960 625141759   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

`sda2` is Android. After doing above changes I got android while I can't access it

[image]
Error :
[image]

> If you didn't create an sdcard image, remove the "SDCARD=/data/sdcard.img" part from the 3rd line (make sure you don't remove anything else!)

(I am sure that I created image... But, I can't find it.. I tried by removing that line also but, same error occurs). Actually when I tried to reinstall again I notice that I didn't get any request to install image file.

> Generating grub configuration file ...
> WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
> Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
> done

`blkid` :

```
istiak@istiak ~ $ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="10C4F74DC4F73416" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Android-x86" UUID="1cf9767a-6334-4490-8ac7-d51aec2b0ac8" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="0A122C29122C1BE7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-03"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="5144d217-9d4a-4e8c-b8d5-31959274dd51" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="b6f4d65c-46a0-4985-9ec3-dd0044257fcb" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="cdead0a2-06"
```

My current code :

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /android-11.13/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-11.13
initrd /android-11.13/initrd.img}
```

Although I get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: kernel]

I noticed that the error was

> error : file/android-11.13-r3/kernel not found

So, I decided to find kernel location in Solus(A Linux distro). There's a way to copy path of any file in Linux. Click on a file than copy(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Then, I found the following path.

> x-special/nautilus-clipboardcopyfile:///run/media/istiak/Android-x86/bliss-x86-11.13/kernel

I removed `x-special/nautilus-clipboardcopyfile:///run/media/istiak/Android-x86/` from that path cause, Android-x86 is detected by `/dev/sda2`. So, I don't need complete path. I made some changes to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /bliss-x86-11.13/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/bliss-x86-11.13
initrd /bliss-x86-11.13/initrd.img}
```

Then, problem solved...! Now, you can use Android.